# Why does my plot end up with points that are two different sizes?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to make a boxplot, with individual data points shown on the plot.  For some reason, though, I end up with two different point sizes.
[image]

I would like to have all my points be size=0.8.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
png(paste("/directory/", hgnc_symbol, "_", curr_gene, ".png", sep=""),
    width=4, height=3, pointsize=1, units="in", res=300)

print({
  barplot <- 
    ggplot(curr_data, aes(x = condition, y = tpm, fill=condition)) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
    geom_jitter(size=0.8) +
    guides(fill=FALSE) +
    theme_bw() + 
    labs(title=paste(hgnc_symbol, "_", curr_gene, sep="")) + 
    labs(x="condition") + labs(y="TPM") + 
    theme(text = element_text(size=5),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size=6))
  })

dev.off()
```

Comment: Could you provide a image of the plot so we know a little more about what we are looking at?

Comment: My question has a link to the plot (where it says "click here to see my plot" in parentheses).

Comment: The bigger dots are outliers from `geom_boxplot`, not `geom_jitter`. If you want to change their size, `geom_boxplot` has an `outlier_size` argument.

Comment: That fixed it!  Thank you, alistaire.  Small correction: the argument is `outlier.size` (period, not underscore).

Comment: Probably better to just remove the outliers if you're using geom_jitter, otherwise the outlier points will be plotted twice. You can remove the outliers with, for example `geom_boxplot(outlier.colour=NA)`.